# Convert data.table string column to POSIXct; round.POSIXt() returns a POSIXlt?

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate, posixct, datetime-conversion

I have a date-time column stored as character in a `data.table`. When I convert to POSIXct and then try rounding to date-only, I get weird results.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# suppose I have these dates, in a data.table
date_chr <- c("2014-04-09 8:37 AM", "2014-09-16 6:04 PM", 
              "2014-09-30 3:26 PM", "2014-11-13 12:47 PM",
              "2014-11-05 12:25 PM")
dat <- data.table(date_chr)

# I convert to POSIXct...
dat[, my_date := ymd_hm(date_chr)]

# ...and I want to round to date only, but this doesn't work
dat[, date_only := round(my_date, 'days')] # why does this return a list?
dat[, date_only := trunc(my_date, 'days')] # this too
```

`class(dat$date_only)` is `list`, and I get this warning message

```
# Warning message:
#   In `[.data.table`(dat, , `:=`(date_only, round(my_date, "days"))) :
#   Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 5 items of column 'date_only' (4 unused)
```

Meanwhile, this works fine!

```
dat_df <- data.frame(date_chr, stringsAsFactors = F)
dat_df$my_date <- ymd_hm(dat_df$date_chr)
dat_df$date_only <- round(dat_df$my_date, 'days')
```

`class(dat_df$date_only)` is `POSIXlt, POSIXt`, as desired.

My question is, why is this and how can I avoid the issue when using `data.table`? There are work-arounds, like truncating the time portion of `date_chr` before converting, but seems like `round.POSIXt()` ought to work.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: To POSIXct: `dat[, my_date := as.POSIXct(date_chr, format = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M")]`, And for date only: 
`dat[, date_only := as.Date(my_date, tz = "Australia/Melbourne")]`

Comment: When you use `round.POSIXt()`, it returns a list (see `?round.POSIXt`), i.e., a `POSIXlt` object.

Comment: Take a look at the [r documentation for dates](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1157/date-and-time#t=201608290453144688076)

Comment: Yes, but I'm interested in why there's a major difference between data.table and data.frame contexts. `dat_df$date_only <- round(dat_df$my_date, 'days')` results in a single new column of class `POSIXt`, while the data.table version doesn't.

Comment: `data.table` does not support [POSIXlt types](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/59) for performance reasons

Comment: Ah. " data.table does not support POSIXlt types" is the answer i'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: @arvi1000 I've extended answer to clarify that storing POSIXlt in data.table is still possible, just not the same way as in data.frame.

Comment: You're welcome; I knew a more knowledgable `data.table`er would be along shortly to expand and give more details in an answer

Comment: [data.table 1.9.4 (Oct 2014) now gives error if you try to create a POSIXlt column](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/59)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already pretty well answered in comments by @SymbolixAU.
Addressing your question about data.frame/data.frame difference on that matter.
Major difference comes from the fact that `POSIXlt` takes much more memory than `POSIXct`, and data.table do care about memory.

```
object.size(Sys.time())
#312 bytes
object.size(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()))
#2144 bytes
```

Important to know is that you can still use `POSIXlt` data type (and its methods) in data.table `j` argument, just make sure to convert it to `POSIXct` when assigning to a column.

If for some reason you want to store POSIXlt in data.table... `data.table` does not support POSIXlt type the same way as data.frame. You can store POSIXlt in data.table but just wrap it into list, as any other non-atomic data type.

Comment: Thanks. Accepting this answer, but you might edit to add "data.table does not support POSIXlt types" for max clarity in posterity

Answer (score 1):

and something like

```
data.table(as.Date(date_chr))
```